# ngx-translate short delay when page loads

Tags: ngx-translate, angular8

I did everything that is explained in the tutorial to implement ngx-translate:

https://www.codeandweb.com/babeledit/tutorials/how-to-translate-your-angular8-app-with-ngx-translate

It is working pretty well, but I noticed that when the page loads for the first time, the ids of the .json files are shown (for less than half of a second) before they are translated. It is no big deal, but it is not perfect as it could be.
e.g 
when page loads "label.name" is shown very quickly then "Name" is displayed after translation.
I don't have any relevant code to show cause I did everything is in the link. 
I would like to know if it is possible to get rid of that?

Answer (score 2):

I sent the issue for the developer and he added the fix at the bottom of the article.

https://www.codeandweb.com/babeledit/tutorials/how-to-translate-your-angular8-app-with-ngx-translate